# Spark DataFrame: How to assign a label to two rows given condition

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a dataframe as follow:

```
+--------+--------+
| Node 1 | Node 2 |
+--------+--------+
|    A   |    B   |
|    B   |    A   |
|    C   |    D   |
|    D   |    C   |
+--------+--------+
```

This data frame is guaranteed to have pairs of node inverted, like A/B and B/A. What I want is label the rows by pairs like that:

```
+--------+--------+-------+
| Node 1 | Node 2 | Label |
+--------+--------+-------+
|    A   |    B   |   1   |
|    B   |    A   |   1   |
|    C   |    D   |   2   |
|    D   |    C   |   2   |
+--------+--------+-------+
```

In this case, I cannot make a label out of A and B and sort the string (`.withColumn('Label', alphabetize_string(concat(Node1, Node2))` because it might repeat the labels with the labels of non inverted nodes that are filtered out of this example but present in my real dataframe.

How do I do this?

Comment: Can you please give example of negative scenarios that you want to avoid

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using PySpark sql functions, `least`, `greatest` to group pairs and then `dense_rank` to get the label column.

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import least,greatest
from pyspark.sql import Window 
w = Window.orderBy(least(col('node_1'),col('node_2')),greatest(col('node_1'),col('node_2'))) 
result = df.withColumn('label',dense_rank().over(w))
result.show()
```